# sql statement with codeigniter active records

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have a table "login_attempts" with the fields: `id`, `ip`, `login_name`, `time`.

I want to achieve this:

Count the number of occurrences for the last 10 minutes for a particular `login_name`.

I'd like to know the query statement in CodeIgniter's active records format?

Comment: Since CI's active record is just a string builder, I'd recommend you won't waste time using it in cases like this, just write a regular query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('COUNT(*) AS count', FALSE);
$this->db->from('login_attempts');
$this->db->where('login_name', $name);
$this->db->where('time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE))', NULL, FALSE);
```

That assumes your table is set up to use Unix timestamps. If that doesn't work, try:

```
$this->db->where('time > TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE))', NULL, FALSE);
```

or:

```
$this->db->where('time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)', NULL, FALSE);
```

Let me know if you have trouble.

Comment: Why was this downvoted??? Is there an error? If so, leave a comment. He didn't specify the format of his time column so I provide three answers to cover all the bases.